# MSVC 2017 15.5.0 - vertical block guide lines

Tags: visual-studio

Just updated my MSVC 2017 to version 15.5.0 and noticed that in C++ files there is now a vertical dashed line connecting open/close bracers. Before now I've seen similar in C# files but didn't care as much.

Now, however, when this feature is auto-enabled for C++ files as well it *drives me nuts*. I hate this with passion yet can't find a way to disable it.

Anyone knows how to **not show** those vertical block guide lines for C++ files?[image]

N.B. I'm posting this question in this section of the site because it matches it the most. Even though this is not strictly speaking a "code" question but it **is** an IDE question so I feel it belongs here.

If it doesn't - let me know where should this question be posted and I'll move it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `Show structure guide lines` in Text Editor->General->Display seciton.

Comment: thank you, that definitely helped. Out of curiosity - can that be done just for few type of files, selectively? I.e. I'd like to have that enabled for HTML (maybe for C#, too).